# Is it possible to install Windows 8 on the SanDisk ReadyCache 32GB SSD drive?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd, format, windows-installation

I bought the SanDisk ReadyCache 32GB SSD drive this week. I didn't know about the caching stuff and thought that I would be able to install Windows 8 on it.

Now I'm using it as a cache drive with the ExpressCache software. But I wonder if it is possible to use this SSD as a primary system drive with an operating system installed on it.

I've tried to format the disk via Windows Disc Manager Tool, but the format option is disabled. Only delete and information options are allowed.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use your SSD as a primary system disk. This is clearly stated by SanDIsc in their user's manual

> **Installing a SanDisk ReadyCache SSD on a desktop computer**
>
> NOTE: The SanDisk ReadyCache SSD is designed to work in conjunction with
> your existing system hard disk drive. Therefore, it **MUST** be installed
> as a non-bootable secondary drive on your desktop computer.

Answer (score 1):

After conducting some research on the web, many forums and the official SanDisk documentation say that you can't install an Operating System on the Ready Cache. However, I have been running windows 7 on a 32GB Ready Cache for months now, and have found it works very smoothly and quickly. I am running it in conjunction with a traditional HDD, where I store most files, but my computer still boots within 20 - 30 seconds, from the Ready Cache.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just tried doing this with a sandisk 32gb ssd. windows 8 says it only needs about 20gb, which it does on the initial install. However, once i ran all the windows updates the drive was completely full. So imo 32gb isn't a big enough drive anyways unless you don't plan to ever run updates.